# how can i define variables in my function?

Tags: python

I am trying to define tp,tn,fp,fn in my function. how can i define them in my function?

from collections import namedtuple
from Corpus import read_classification_from_file
import os

## my updated code

```
def compute_confusion_matrix(truth_dict, pred_dict,pos_tag=True,neg_tag=False):
    tp=0
    fn=0
    tn=0
    fp=0
    for i in truth_dict.keys():
            if (truth_dict[i] == pos_tag):
                    if(pred_dict[i] == pos_tag):
                            tp += 1
                    else:
                            fn += 1
            else:
                     if(pred_dict[i] != pos_tag):
                             tn += 1
                     else:
                             fp += 1
    ConfMat = namedtuple('ConfMat', 'tp tn fp fn')
    p=ConfMat(tp, tn, fp, fn)
    return p

                      
def quality_score(tp,tn,fp,fn):
    return (tp + tn)/(tp + tn + 10 * fp + fn)

def compute_quality_for_corpus(corpus_dir):
    truth_dict = read_classification_from_file(os.path.join(corpus_dir, "!truth.txt"))
    pred_dict = read_classification_from_file(os.path.join(corpus_dir, "!prediction.txt"))
    cm2 = compute_confusion_matrix(truth_dict, pred_dict,pos_tag='SPAM',neg_tag='OK')
    cm2=(cm.tp,cm.tn,cm.fp,cm.fn)
    return quality_score(tp,tn,fp,fn)
```

Comment: Those variables are defined in the functions where you define them, and undefined where they are not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have some typos with the cm2 lines(appearance of cm), but that's easily fixable. When you access fields in a named tuple you can use dot notation.

```
cm2 = compute_confusion_matrix(truth_dict,pred_dict,pos_tag='SPAM',neg_tag='OK')
return quality_score(cm2.tp,cm2.tn,cm2.fp,cm2.fn)
```

Comment: i actually calculated it in another function compute_confusion_matrix and i want to just defined as that function

Comment: i remember a way to use cm. something

Comment: you can pass the variables to this function through parameters, or use the global keyword

Comment: compute_confusion_matrix returns ConfMat(tp=2, tn=2, fp=0, fn=0) and i want to use the values of the variables in the return quality

Comment: Assuming that ConfMat is an object, called cm2, then you can use corpus_dir.tp to access that value. If it is a tuple, then simply use cm[0], cm[1]... up to the max index to access the values.

Comment: exactly and i got stuck trying to write cm with cm2 and always i got error tp is not defined  , can you please fix my code

Comment: add the function compute_confusion_matrix to your original post

Comment: i edited my post with my complete codes

Comment: i am still getting error: ":tp is not defined" , would you write for me?

Comment: Actually post the entire code, I may have to run this myself to see what's going on.

Comment: actually after using cm2.tp as you said above it worked well ,thanks

Comment: btw, I realized that your original method of namedtuple is correct, just to let you know